# Trace route of a symbolic link

Tags: symlink, readlink

I want to resolve a symbolic link with the additional option to print the whole linkage. For example I want to run a command like `readlink -f "symlink2"` which reports each entry of the linkage. In other words if you would resolve the symbolic link "symlink2->symlink1->/path/file" then the result of command above is "/path/file" and I am lokking for a output like:

```
$readlink -f "symlink2
symlink1
/path/file
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017500/how-to-see-full-symlink-path. If this isn't a duplicate, can you edit or rephrase your question to explain why `readlink -f symlinkName` doesn't work for you to display the real path of the symlink.

Comment: @Christia, this information you like to know should already there. But thx for your evidence, I edited my question to clarify my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is to make your own recursive `readlink`.

```
function readlinkWithPrint() {
    link=`readlink "$@"`
    [ -e "$link" ] && echo "$link"
    [ -h "$link" ] && readlinkWithPrint "$link"
}
```

Here's a test:

```
$ touch file
$ ln -s file symlink1
$ ln -s symlink1 symlink2
$ readlinkWithPrint symlink2
symlink1
file
```

Unfortunately, this function is quite basic; the options you provide to frist `readlink` will not propagate to the rest plus you cannot read multiple files.

Comment: Thx for that code snippet. It seems to define a own function in `~/.bashrc` is the only way.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for [`namei`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/namei.1.html), which is part of the util-linux suite, available on every non-embedded Linux system.

See [this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/143631/is-there-a-command-like-namei-for-os-x) regarding an equivalent for macOS. The [source code](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/tree/misc-utils/namei.c) should be mostly portable if you need it on some other Unix variant.

Comment: this is exactly what I am looking for! thank you so much :-)